# The target entry-point "@angular/material/card" has missing dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, npm

I am trying to deploy a web application on heroku but I am getting the following error:

```
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-logger : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/core : es2015 as esm2015
An error occurred during the build:
Error: The target entry-point "@angular/material/card" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/cdk/a11y
 - @angular/cdk/bidi
 - @angular/cdk
 - @angular/cdk/coercion
 - @angular/cdk/platform
 - @angular/cdk/keycodes
    at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (/tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
    at /tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/analyze_entry_points.js:29:41
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (/tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:28:29)
    at /tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:57:59
    at SyncLocker.lock (/tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/locking/sync_locker.js:34:24)
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (/tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:57:27)
    at Object.mainNgcc (/tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/main.js:74:25)
    at Object.process (/tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/index.js:29:23)
    at NgccProcessor.processModule (/tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:164:16)
    at /tmp/build_fbe19cdb/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:128:18
An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@angular/material/card" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/cdk/a11y
 - @angular/cdk/bidi
 - @angular/cdk
 - @angular/cdk/coercion
 - @angular/cdk/platform
 - @angular/cdk/keycodes
See "/tmp/ng-zGDljs/angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! web-mobile@0.0.0 build: `ng build --prod`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

I don't quite understand the issue here. I am able to build the application on my local machine without any problems e.g.

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/ dist/ && npm i && ng build
```

builds successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- @angular/cdk/a11y
- @angular/cdk/bidi
- @angular/cdk
- @angular/cdk/coercion
- @angular/cdk/platform
- @angular/cdk/keycode

These are the dependencies missing. You might want to check if these are installed.

Comment: Interesting. `@angular/cdk` is not present in the `package.json` - why am I able to build this locally then?

Comment: Where are you trying to build this, other than in local ?

Comment: I am deploying this on heroku, where it gets built and served after pusing it to the main branch. It's weird ..

Comment: Did you check if you have cdk package in local ?
Without that, there is no way it can be run, as far as I know.